# ES6 Modules: Must you explicitly define variables before returning them?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

Before I gave my JavaScript file `type="module"` , I could define my variables in the same statement that I used to return them.

Example:

```
function formatNameForFile(name) {
    return formattedName = name.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-');
}
```

However, once I did add `type="module"` to my JavaScript file, I received the following reference error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: formattedName is not defined
```

I could eliminate these errors by explicitly defining my variables prior to returning them, like so:

```
function formatNameForFile(name) {
    const formattedName = name.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-');
    return formattedName;
}
```

Why is this? Aren't these variables still accessible via the initial return statement so long as they are bound (using `const`, `var`, or `let`) within it?

Comment: Just use: `return name.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-');`.

Comment: In the case above you should just use `return name.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-');`

Comment: Are you trying to define an outer/global variable at the same time? If so, you should explicitly declare it at the scope where it is intended. Then your code will work, though I don't think that's a great approach.

Comment: It makes no sense giving your return value a variable name.

Comment: @slappy yes, good point. I do not actually need to declare any variables. I've switched to just using return statements, as was mentioned above by iAmOren and Tamas Szoke . Thanks for the help, all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ES6 modules are [always strict](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

> The entire contents of JavaScript modules are automatically in strict mode, with no statement needed to initiate it.

In strict mode, when you attempt to assign to a variable which hasn't been defined yet, an error is thrown:

```js
'use strict';
something = 'foo';
```

This is what's happening in your module. Since the variable name has not been defined anywhere inside the function or in any of its parent scopes, an error gets thrown.

> Aren't these variables still accessible via the initial return statement so long as they are bound (using const, var, or let) within it?

Sure, but you can't refer to or assign to a variable which has *not* been initialized yet.

But there's no need to create a variable that you're immediately going to return. If you wanted, you could do

```
const formatNameForFile = name => name.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-');
```

Comment: Ah ok, got it. Thank you, this is a great explanation. This is just one example, but all of the functions this pertains to are reused within other functions, so I do need to maintain references to the variables. This is very helpful, though - thank you

Comment: Sorry, I now see what you mean about not needing to declare variables. Using a return statement by itself does work fine. Thanks again